# Issue encoding an email for my app

Tags: python, django, forms, python-2.7, email

I am configuring an app that operates subscriptions only with emails, all runs perfectly except a part of my form that should encode all email received.

This is the error obtained when i sign up with an email:

```
**Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing**

Traceback: File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89. return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  214. if form.is_valid(): 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  184. return self.is_bound and not self.errors 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  176. self.full_clean() 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  393. self._clean_form() 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/AMBIENTE1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  417. cleaned_data = self.clean() 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/GIRASOL/apps/newsletter/forms.py" in clean
  47. self.cleaned_data['activation_key'] = generate_activation_key(data['email']) 
File "/home/draicore/SUNFLOWER/GIRASOL/apps/newsletter/forms.py" in generate_activation_key
  16. salt = hashlib.md5(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:10]

Exception Type: TypeError at /request/ 
Exception Value: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

I have this code that is responsible of encoding emails on my forms.py:

```
def generate_activation_key(email):
    if isinstance(email, str):
        email = email.encode('utf-8')
    salt = hashlib.md5(str(random.random()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:10]
    return hashlib.md5(salt+email).hexdigest()


class EmailSubscriberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label=_('Email'), required=True)
    captcha = CaptchaField(label=_('Security code'))
    activation_key = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    activation_request_sent_at = forms.DateField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = EmailSubscriber
        fields = (
            'email',
            'activation_key',
            'activation_request_sent_at',
        )

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].strip()
        try:
            self.instance = EmailSubscriber.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
            if self.instance is not None:
                return email.lower()
        except EmailSubscriber.DoesNotExist:
            return email.lower()
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('This email is already subscribed.'))

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if 'email' in data:
            self.cleaned_data['activation_key'] = generate_activation_key(data['email'])
            self.cleaned_data['activation_request_sent_at'] = timezone.now()
        return self.cleaned_data
```

I believe that this issue is caused for an incompatibility of version of python (i have Python 3.4.1) and i was trying to looking for solutions here in other questions and i found answers that say about a new format to set the .encode('utf-8'). and I dont know what i should change.

apologizeme in advance if I overlook something. Any contribution is wellcome, Thanks for evaluate!

Have a great day!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also encode your `random` salt string:

```
str(random.random()).encode('utf-8')
```

However, then you'll receive a new error...because `email` is `bytes` and `salt` is a `string`. I'll leave it up to you to determine how you want to normalize these so that they can be added together.

Comment: Thank you for evaluate! I had tried to write it that way but so i obtain this error `Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly` as you said

Comment: That's what I said in the second part of my answer. You need to either convert `email` to a string, or `salt` to bytes.